# What is C:\Intel\ExtremeGraphics\CUI\Resource and can it be deleted

Tags: windows-7

What is this subtree? Why does Intel get special treatment here and is allowed a root level directory on C: for nothing? The directory tree is empty. OK to delete ?

Cheers,
Gert

Update:

@Adam & @Karan. Renamed it and booted many times by now. No negative effect. Though there is one non-empty sub dir : C:\Intel_BLA\Logs. –

```
C:\Intel_BLA\Logs>dir
 Volume in drive C has no label.
 Volume Serial Number is 08C1-428C

 Directory of C:\Intel_BLA\Logs

09/13/2014  09:01 PM    <DIR>          .
09/13/2014  09:01 PM    <DIR>          ..
09/13/2014  08:57 PM            37,128 IntelAMT.log
09/13/2014  08:56 PM           921,420 IntelChipset.log
09/13/2014  09:01 PM                 0 IntelCPHS.log
09/13/2014  08:58 PM            39,292 IntelGFX.log
09/13/2014  08:58 PM               740 IntelGFXCoin.log
09/13/2014  08:58 PM            44,564 IntelOCL.log
09/13/2014  09:01 PM            40,062 IntelUSB3.log
       7 File(s)      1,083,206 bytes
       2 Dir(s)  147,023,450,112 bytes free

C:\Intel_BLA\Logs>
```

Comment: I think it should be ok to delete. Most probably it's a remnant of the driver package being installed. I would advise you to move it somewhere though and reboot once, then get rid of it if nothing complains.

Answer (score 3):

This is definitely a remnant of Intel's Extreme Graphics driver you once had installed. If there's nothing in it, it's completely safe to remove the whole directory. Be sure to check each folder and not just the deepest one before doing so.

Additionally, it's good to enable viewing of critical system files when doing this. Because it's a directory in the root instead of Program Files, there is a chance there are hidden and very important system files in there.

Answer (score 0):

My logs directory has files in it related to the Intel chipset on the motherboard.

While it may be a remnant, I do not think it wise to erase it.